# display array words with different pauses

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript array:

```
["joe", "james", "jane", "jim", "jack", "ADAM", "jill", "jake", "John", "joel", "jeff", "CHARLES"]
```

The idea is to display all the lowercase names for 500ms second then replace with the next lowercase name (also for 500ms). When I get to the capitalized names, I want it stay on for 5000ms. Ideally there is a pattern of 5 lowercase and 1 capitalized.

Comment: `The idea is` ... well the idea of SO is to show some code that you are having an issue with ... see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must:

```js
//<![CDATA[
var pre = onload, doc, bod, E, weirdWait; // for use on other loads
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre(); // use different var name to hold more loads on other pages
doc = document; bod = doc.body;
E = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id); // hope you learned something here
}
weirdWait = function(displayDiv, yourArray, timerDiv){
  var i = 0;
  displayDiv.innerHTML = yourArray[i];
  if(timerDiv)timerDiv.innerHTML = new Date().toString();
  function recurse(){
    var si = setInterval(function(){
      i++;
      if(!yourArray.hasOwnProperty(i))i = 0;
      var val = yourArray[i];
      displayDiv.innerHTML = val;
      if(timerDiv)timerDiv.innerHTML = new Date().toString();
      if(val.match(/^[A-Z]/)){
        clearInterval(si); setTimeout(recurse, 4500);
      }  
    }, 500);
  }
  recurse();
}
var yourArray = ['joe', 'james', 'jane', 'jim', 'jack', 'ADAM', 'jill', 'jake', 'John', 'joel', 'jeff', 'CHARLES'];
weirdWait(E('output'), yourArray, E('timer'));
}
//]]>
```

```css
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
.main{
  width:940px; background:#000; color:#fff; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
#output{
  font:bold 64px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>weird wait</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <div id='output'></div>
    <div id='timer'></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! this helped

Answer (score 1):

I don't actually know Javascript but here's some c# which you should be able to convert by looking at it

I'm assuming the "John" is supposed to be "john"

```
for (int i = 0; i < NameArray.Length; i++)
{
    if (NameArray[i] == NameArray[i].ToLower()) //Javascript equivalent would be .toLowerCase()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(NameArray[i]);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500); //Javascript equivalent would be wait(500)
    }
    else if (NameArray[i] == NameArray[i].ToUpper()) //Javascript equivalent would be .toUpperCase()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(NameArray[i]);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); //Javascript equivalent would be wait(5000)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```js
const array = ["joe", "james", "jane", "jim", "jack", "ADAM", "jill", "jake", "JOHN", "joel", "jeff", "CHARLES"];

function recursiveStaggeredLoop (arr, i) {
  while (i < array.length) {
    if (array[i] === array[i].toLowerCase()) {
      console.log(array[i]);
      i++
      return setTimeout(() => {
        return recursiveStaggeredLoop(array, i);
      }, 500)
    } 
    else if (array[i] === array[i].toUpperCase()) {
      console.log(array[i])
      i++
      return setTimeout(() => {
        return recursiveStaggeredLoop(array, i)
      }, 5000)
    }
  }
  console.log('all done')
}

recursiveStaggeredLoop(array, 0)
```

I just use a simple `while` loop and recursion here, gets the job done.

One quick note, it only works with strictly lowercase or uppercase names. Your original array had a "John" which would break this code. But this should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
const names = ["joe", "james", "jane", "jim", "jack", "ADAM", "jill", "jake", "John", "joel", "jeff", "CHARLES"];

const displayName = (index, max) => {
  if (max === index) {
    return;
  } 

  // set your html to the name

  const timeout = names[index] === names[index].toUpperCase() ? 5000 : 500;
  setTimeout(displayName(index + 1, max), timeout); 
}

displayName(0, names.length);
```

Ill leave the figuring out how to display it to you, theres many ways to do that such as setting the innerHtml of a div.